# Spree vs Solidus for Shopify like application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, multi-tenant, spree, solidus

We are building a multi-tenant SaaS application where our users can easily build e-commerce sites of their own; very similar to what Shopify offers, except that this will be tailored to a specific kind of goods industry - custom integrations with industry partners, integrations with our users' company CRM systems, etc.

Examples of customisations:

- A single admin should be able to manage multiple stores
- Obviously, like Shopify, each store would have its own set of users / customers and subdomain
- The order processing mechanism should be different for each store - store A might need to call an external API to place the order while store B might just need to add an entry in a spreadsheet.

Within our team, we have extensive Ruby on Rails experience, so I think going with [Spree](https://spreecommerce.org) or [Solidus](https://solidus.io) is the way forward.

But we are finding it hard to choose between one over the other as this will be a long term investment.

Does anybody have enough experience with both of them to be able to objectively compare?

Comment: I'm doing the same research. Spree seems to have more out of box support for multi-vendor. Then I'm comparing it with Vendure and haven't decided. 

What's your conclusion in the end? @aksay?

Comment: We have pretty much zeroed in on Spree. 
1. The initial feedback we have gotten is that finding developers with Spree experience is slightly easier compared to Solidus. 
2. Spree already has multi store support out-of-the-box (one of our main requirements) to a decent extent.
3. Spree also seems to have come up with a decent roadmap that they seem to be achieving fast

Comment: have you run Spree once in your local machine? bundle install kept hanging for me. Meanwhile I'm exploring Node.js based ecommerce frameworks.

Comment: Oh yeah, we have already started working on it. We didn't face any issues actually.

Answer (score 1):

From the 2 you've mentioned only Spree has a built-in multi-store mechanism. Solidus is a single-tenant application.